# Knights, Knaves, and Normals Puzzle - A: "B is a normal", B: "C is a normal", C: "B is a normal"

Tags: logic, puzzle

> You are on an island inhabited by three types of people: knights (always make true statements), knaves (always make false statements) and normals (sometimes make true statements and sometimes make false statements).
>
> You come across 3 people Adam, Ben and Carl. You know that one is a knight, one is a knave and one is a normal. They say the following:
>
> - Adam: "Ben is a normal."
> - Ben: "Carl is a normal."
> - Carl: "Ben is a normal."
>
> Determine which person is what or whether you do not have enough information.

**My Attempt**

**Adam:**

- Adam is a knight => Ben is a normal
- Adam is a knave => Ben is a knight or Ben is a knave
- Adam is a normal

  - If Adam is true, Ben is a normal
  - If Adam is false, Ben is a knight or Ben is a knave

**Ben:**

- Ben is a knight => Carl is a normal
- Ben is a knave => Carl is a knight or Carl is a knave
- Ben is a normal

  - If Ben is true, Carl is a normal
  - If Ben is false, Carl is a knight or Carl is a knave

**Carl:**

- Carl is a knight => Ben is a normal
- Carl is a knave => Ben is a knight or Ben is a knave
- Carl is a normal

  - If Carl is true, Ben is a normal
  - If Carl is false, Ben is a knight or Ben is a knave

1. Adam is a knight => Ben is a normal => Carl is a knave (can't be normal since Ben is one and can't be a knight since A is one) => Ben is a knight or Ben is a knave which contradicts the fact that Ben is a normal.
2. Adam is a knave => Ben is a knight (can't be a knave) => Carl is a normal => Ben is a knight (can't be a normal or a knave).
3. Adam is a normal => Ben is a knight or knave (can't be normal) => Carl is normal (not possible, so eliminated) or Carl is a knight (can't be knave) => Ben is a normal (not possible since Adam is a normal).

*Therefore, Adam is a knave, Ben is a knight and Carl is a normal*

**My Question**
Does my solution seem correct and make sense?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: simpler:  $A,C$ are either both telling the truth or both lying.  The first is impossible since it would force one of them to be normal.  So they are both lying. Thus one of them is a knave and the other  is a (lying) normal .  Thus $B$ is a knight.  So $C$ is normal, and we are done.

Comment: See [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: At the time that I was composing my answer, the comment of @lulu didn't exist.  Actually, my answer is simply a duplicate of lulu's comment, which time-stamp beat me.

Comment: @user2661923  no worries.  In my view, comments never take priority over full solutions.  Anything anybody leaves in a comment is fair game for use, or it may be ignored.  Certainly, I don't always read all the comments when I post a solution to something.

Comment: @lulu For what it's worth, my personal feeling is that if the response exists at the time that I first encounter the problem, then I should not duplicate the analysis.  In rare cases, I might invite the first responder to re-post a comment as an answer.  Then, after a couple of hours, if that isn't done, and I think that the math is very relevant, I will post an answer indicating that I am merely duplicating someone else's comment.  However, if the response doesn't exist when I start to compose, then it becomes fair game, because otherwise you get into a nonsensical time-stamp race.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct and also seems valid, though I didn't read it that closely.

I can't resist posting a shortcut analysis.

Assume Ben normal.
Then one of Adam or Carl must be a knight, and the other a knave.
This yields a contradiction, because you can not ever have a knight and knave make the same statement.

Therefore, Ben is not normal.
Therefore, at least one of Adam or Carl must be a knave, since they have both lied about Ben.

Therefore, Ben is also not a knave, and therefore Ben must be a knight.

At this point, everything falls into place.

Comment: Wow! That's a very elegant way to look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since I am very lazy, I like methods that don't involve much "thinking" ;-) (I mean thinking through options, assumptions, and trees). So I did it this way:

First, notation: A is a knight is AT, A is a normal is AN, A is a knave is AF.

Now, construct pretty automatically the following XORs (where pq is p ^ q):

AN + ATBN + AFBT = 1

BN + BTCN + BFCT = 1

CN + CTBN + CFBT = 1

Multiply both sides of the equations, noting that any terms with AXAY, BXBY, or CXCY (X ≠ Y) are 0.

You are left with AFBTCN = 1. That is Adam is a knave, Ben is a knight, and Carl is normal.